# Extreme Value Theory Quantile Estimation

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, probability-limit-theorems

I have been reading Coles' and De Haan's books on Extreme Value Theory, and the suggestion is made as a starting point that one can start with a sample, break it into blocks, find the maximum of each block, fit these to a Generalized Extreme Value Distribution using one of several options for parameter estimation (I just used MLE as a starting point). An application seems to be estimating quantiles for very unlikely extreme events. That is: it is suggested in Coles' book that the quantile for the $p=1/100$ threshold for the **original** distribution can be estimated by the $p=1/100$ threshold for the **extreme value** distribution. That is to say, if $\hat{G}$ is the MLE for the GEVD associated to $M_n=\max_{i\leq n}\{X_i\}$ and $F_{X_i}$ the CDF for X_i, then $$F_{X_i}^{-1}(1-p)\approx \hat{G}^{-1}(1-p).$$
It's not obvious to me at all based on what I'm seeing in the book if this is the case or why it would be the case. In computing this for 1000 samples of standard exponentially distributed R.V. with block size 25, I recovered $\hat{G}^{-1}(1-\frac{1}{100})\approx7,$ whereas the actual answer is $F^{-1}(.99)=-\log(.01)\approx 4.6...$ I feel like I must be missing something fundamental.

Comment: Maybe you can experiment with block sizes other than 25 to check which block size works the best for you.

Comment: It definitely seems like a higher block size helps. I've read that there is a tradeoff with choosing the block size between bias and accuracy, but I don't necessarily know how or why that comes to be.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the quantile functions for $F$ and $G$ for your entire simulated data. If you plot histograms of $F^{-1}(u)$ and $G^{-1}(u)$, $u \in [0,1]$ it should have a uniform distribution. If it does not then that implies $F$ and $G$ are not the right fit for your data.

The beauty of the probability integral transform (which is what you are doing here) is that it allows you to translate between many distributions and the underlying quantiles are always the same. So by transforming your original function to a uniform distribution using its CDF, you can then transform this uniform distribution to any other distribution using the quantile function for this distribution. These distributions are all rooted in the same uniform distribution, so by selecting any threshold, e.g., 0.9, you can the find what that threshold corresponds to in different distributions using their quantile functions.